# Alien killing people by shooting his fingernails

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I've been looking for this movie for several years and found nothing. I guess it wasn't popular. The action takes place on another planet. I don't remember much of the story line, just that there was a cute little alien. And one of the crew members fed it with a chocolate bar. And another member was being cruel to it, and it killed the human by shooting him with his poisonous fingernail. The alien had three fingers.

It's an old movie. I watched it in the late 90's as a kid, and wasn't able to watch it till the end so don't remember much unfortunately.

Comment: Three fingers and poison body-darts makes me think of *Critters* (and sequels) but I don't know if anyone has ever described them as "cute," and I don't recall them being satisfied with a bit of chocolate.

Comment: Super Metroid and some other video games in its franchise play on a non-Earth planet. They have cute little aliens (etecoons). The non-cute alien with three fingers (Kraid) tries to kill the genetically engineered human protagonist (Samus) by shooting fingernails at her. Players are divided between being kind or cruel to the etecoons. I don't recall anyone feeding a chocolate bar though. You could have watched Super Metroid in the late 90s.

Comment: This sounds like the show Earth 2, with the kobas as the fingernail-dart aliens.

Comment: @RLH I know it was a long time ago, but it is Earth 2! thank you so much